# Python - libvirt

Tags: python, qemu, kvm, libvirt

Is it possible to create a VM from KVM hypervisor using libvirt-python API?
I have an iso that I downloaded from a cloud directly. I could not find any example on the internet.

Cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

sure libvirt-python is designed to do that. You just need to open a connection and call defineXML() with a well formated XML.

```
import libvirt
conn = libvirt.open('qemu+ssh://root@yourhost/system')
conn.defineXML(imagine_a_well_formated_domain_xml_here)
```

Now the domain is defined, you can start it:

```
dom = conn.lookupByName(the_domain_name)
dom.create() # start the domain
```